# PHP exec() function speedup

Tags: php, powershell, exec, command-line-interface

I am using the `exec()` function in PHP to run a command via command prompt. However the time which is needed to process this command using PHP is much longer compared to when I actually run the command on the *CLI*.

Any idea how I can improve its performance or make more efficient calls? I am trying to run powershell scripts.

Comment: PowerShell? Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: @Manngo Yes I am running on Windows. Why?

Comment: That will affect the nature of the problem. Using Windows, you have the choice of Apache or the current equivalent of IIS, among others. You also have a choice of how PHP is implemented. Classically, PHP on IIS has been woefully slow, but I understand that it’s no longer so bad. I’m not a Windows user, so I can’t tell from experience.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec()` function needs to create another process, a virtual shell, run the command, wait for the reply, and then return with the results, if any.

That’s the sort of thing you can expect whenever you want PHP, or some other platform, to communicate outside of itself.

There are the following alternatives:

- Simple shell commands have corresponding PHP functions. This includes basic file manipulation.
- If you’re using `exec` to call another program, such as ImageMagick, there may be an interface available to PHP directly.
- There may be alternative PHP scripts available to do the same job as a command line process.

Other than that, maybe not.

Comment: I'm using the exec() function to call powershell.exe which in turn is used to run my script

Comment: If you’re running PowerShell to do file management stuff, you can still look at doing it directly in PHP. In any case, you can always expect the extra step to take longer, but I’m not sure how much longer.